# Remove part of string (downcase) and keep the original (upcase) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I would like to remove a set of words from a ruby string, using the lowercase and unaccented version of the words, and keep the original string with the current casing and the current accents.

For example:

```
string = "Château Dupont Vallée du Rhône" 
stopwords= "vallee du Rhone"
```

Desired output: `string = "Château Dupont"`

What I can do so far is using a lowercase unaccented strings to remove the words:

```
string = "chateau dupont vallee du rhone" 
stopword = "vallee du rhone"
```

Example output: `string = "chateau dupont"`

In fact, I want to get the original string but remove a string using the lowercase unaccented version of the words.

My code:

```
def remove_appellations_in_string(string, region_id)
   down_trans_string = I18n.transliterate(string.dup)      
   # custom request to order by max length in name            
   stopwords.each do |stop|
      # downcase/unaccent stopword
      down_trans_stop = I18n.transliterate(stop.name.downcase)
      # remove
      down_trans_string.gsub!(down_trans_stop, ' ')
    end    
    return ' ' + string + ' ' 
  end
```

I suppose I need to use a regex OR get a way to obtain the indexes of the stopwords to remove them from the original string.

Comment: Try something like `def remove_appellations_in_string(string, region_id)
   stopwords.each do |stop|
      rx = stop.name.chars.map { |c| "[#{c}#{I18n.transliterate(c)}]" }.join 
      string.gsub!(Regexp.new(rx, 'i'), ' ')
    end    
    return ' ' + string + ' ' 
  end`. Here is a code snippet - https://ideone.com/IevjIW

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the indexes of the cars".

Comment: What is `I18n`? If you are using some library, then please refer to that.

Comment: What is `stopwords`?

Comment: The Wiktor answer works like a charm ! But `rx = I18n.transliterate(stop.name)` works also, with the regexp `string.gsub!(Regexp.new(rx, 'i'), ' ')`. SO what is the advantage of `rx = stop.name.chars.map { |c| "[#{c}#{I18n.transliterate(c)}]" }.join` ?

Comment: @alex.bour Well, I am not sure now after your latest comment. I thought stop words may contain accented letters. I can't get it why that worked as `/vallee/i` can't match `Vallée`, `/vall[eé][eé]/i` will.

Comment: Yes, I confirm that the stopword may contains accented letters, that's why I used I18n.transliterate(stop). Another problem is the original string can also contains accented letters... So does the reverse is true ? Does original `Vallée` can match the stopword `vallee` AS original `vallee` can match the stopword `vallée`  ?

Comment: @alex.bour No, it won't. I suggest using a hash of mappings like `e` -> `[ée]`  and replace each char in stopword with these character classes, then build the case insensitive regex using the constructor and replace with `gsub` from the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
string = "Château Dupont Vallée du Rhône"   
stopword = "vallee du rhone"  
index = I18n.transliterate(string).downcase.index(I18n.transliterate(stopword).downcase)
string[0..(index - 1)] + string[(index + stopword.length)..-1]

# => "Château Dupont "

stopword = "Dupont" 
index = I18n.transliterate(string).downcase.index(I18n.transliterate(stopword).downcase)
string[0..(index - 1)] + string[(index + stopword.length)..-1]

# => "Château  Vallée du Rhône"
```

It does as you've suggested - grabs the index of where the stopword matches a stripped string, and returns the text before and after this.

Is that what you're after? Let me know how you get on with it or if you've any questions.

Comment: Note that transliterating a string does not necessarily end up with a string of the same length.

Comment: Hello, Yes, it's a thing like this ! Thanks SRack. I made a few changes to clarify things. `index_stopword_start = unaccent_string.index(unaccent_stopword)        
        next if index_stopword_start.nil?
        
        index_stopword_end = index_stopword_start + unaccent_stopword.length
        
        # new string
        string = string[0..(index_stopword_start - 1)] + string[index_stopword_end..-1]`

Comment: Sawa, yes I know that transliterate can be a problem with some languages. Thanks.

Comment: Did this work as an answer @alex.bour? If so, suitable to accept it?